# GridView goes messy

Tags: java, android, gridview

When I scroll past an item and come back to it, it changes it's position until I click on it, then it will correctly align itself. How can I solve this. Sorry I am still at the start of the project so my code is a bit messy.
This is my code:

```
package com.example.r_corp.androidslauncher;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    PackageManager packageManager;
Intent mainIntent = null;

static ArrayList<app> appList;
static GridView gridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_all_apps_layout);
    gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridView);
    gridView.setNumColumns(4);

    packageManager = getPackageManager();
    mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    appList = getApps();
    show();

}

public ArrayList<app> getApps(){
    List<ResolveInfo>apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

    ArrayList<app> Apps = new ArrayList();
    for(ResolveInfo ri : apps){
        app App = new app();

        App.icon = ri.loadIcon(packageManager);
        App.Name = ri.loadLabel(packageManager).toString();

        Apps.add(App);
    }
    return Apps;
}

public void show(){

    ArrayAdapter<app> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<app>(this, R.layout.item,
            appList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item,null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            appList.get(position).icon.setBounds(10,10,10,10);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(appList.get(position).icon);

            appIcon.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            appIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            appIcon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

            TextView appName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView);
            appName.setText(appList.get(position).Name);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    gridView.setFocusable(true);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


}
class app{
    Drawable icon;
    String Name;
}
```

show_all_apps_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/GridView"/>
```

item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your helpfulness.

Comment: `it changes it's position until I click on it, then it will correctly align itself.` can you explain this a little more? you didn't provide a click listener so it shouldn't be doing anything if you click on it. maybe upload some screenshots

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for tying to help man. Appreciate it. I had to set layout params for the text view.:)